# when listview starts loading new data the scrolling hangs it neither goes upward not downwards till data get loaded.?

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

when my listview starts loading new data the scrolling hangs it neither goes upward not downwards till data get loaded. Is there any way to slove this issue???

Answer (score 1):

You can do data fetching task on seperate thread and Update the ListView in Handler.

Refer this-

http://negativeprobability.blogspot.in/2011/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-listview.html

Answer (score 0):

use progress dialog in your AsyncTask's  `onPostExecute` and `onPreExecute`.

start it from *onPreExecute* & stop it in *onPostExecute*

after downloading completion, set the new data in *adapter* & use `notifyDataSetChanged`, put this code in *onPostExecute*

Comment: I am doing in thew same way but still scrollbar hangs and not responding till data loads

Comment: probably you need the user to prevent scrolling during data loading, that's why use progress dialog before start downloading from onPreExecute, then download data from doInBackground & while download completes set new data and refresh the adapter... then dismiss the progress dialog from  onPostExecute.